# Why is my Automator Print Plugin Only Running Every Other Time?

Tags: automator, pdf, printing, plugins, macos

I have set up a simple Print Plugin in Automator.  It renames the file, then moves the file to a particular directory.  No matter how simple I make the plugin, it only triggers every other time I run it.

In other words, I go into Print > PDF > then select the automator script from the dropdown box.

The first time, it appears to "print" but nothing happens; the second time, it runs as expected.

I've looked through my logs, and it appears I get an unrelated error log about Automator Runner on the second time I run the plugin -- it is as though the Automator script isn't getting run in the first instance.

I'm using Mountain Lion.

Any thoughts or suggestions?  I'm not even sure where to look next.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob Walker writes:

> Just saw your note on the Apple Support webpage.  I was able to get past the apparent bug by saving the Automator Script as an Automator "Application" rather than a Print Plugin. I saved it to ~/Library/PDF Services and it shows up and works as expected.

This also worked for me.

Comment: Can you add a link to the post you referenced? Thanks!